# Parsing attribute values of nested XML nodes

Tags: php, xml, parsing

Im trying to parse XML in PHP, but I am having problems with it.

So the XML looks like this (simplified)

```
<weatherdata>
 <forecast>
 <tabular>
   <time from="2015-09-25T20:00:00" to="2015-09-25T23:00:00" period="3">
      <symbol number="4" numberEx="4" name="Cloudy" var="04" />
   </time>
   <time from="2015-09-25T23:00:00" to="2015-09-26T05:00:00" period="0">
      <symbol number="9" numberEx="46" name="Light rain" var="46" />
   </time>
```

.....

I was able to load all the time->from values like this:

```
foreach($xml->forecast->tabular as $forecastItem){
    $attr = $forecastItem->attributes();
    $froms[] = $attr['from'];       
}
```

But then I tried to load the name attribute of the symbol like this:

```
foreach($xml->forecast->tabular as $forecastItem){
    $attr = $forecastItem->attributes();
    $froms[] = $attr['from'];
    $attr2 = $forecastItem->symbol->attributes();
    $names[] = $attr2['name'];
}
```

and it shows me an error that main() node does not exist. Basically what I would like to do is load all the names into an array, just like the froms.

Answer (score 2):

The full error message you get is:

> Warning: main(): Node no longer exists in ...

followed by the line-number of the following code:

```
$attr2 = $forecastItem->symbol->attributes();
```

It might not be clear to you what the error actually is about. To better understand it you have to know a little about the inner working of the **SimpleXmlElement** you make use of here.

If you access a child-element by it's name, for examle like here the `<symbol>` element:

```
$forecastItem->symbol
```

the SimpleXML extension will create the node on-the-fly as a temporary one, whenever no such child-element already exists. This is done to allow adding it on the fly. For example:

```
$forecastItem->symbol = 'hello world!';

echo $forecastItem->asXML();
```

would display:

```
<tabular>
   <time from="2015-09-25T20:00:00" to="2015-09-25T23:00:00" period="3">
      <symbol number="4" numberEx="4" name="Cloudy" var="04"/>
   </time>
   <time from="2015-09-25T23:00:00" to="2015-09-26T05:00:00" period="0">
      <symbol number="9" numberEx="46" name="Light rain" var="46"/>
   </time>
 <symbol>hello world!</symbol></tabular>
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

And that also explains why your code does not work. As the *symbol* element is only temporary, and you don't set it, SimpleXML just tries to tell you, that *this node doesn't exist any longer*. And rightly so, as you try to read the attributes from a non-existing node:

```
$forecastItem->symbol->attributes(); // no write, but a read operation
```

So it then works as expected if the node exists, e.g. this existing symbol element:

```
$forecastItem->time->symbol->attributes();
```

Which most likely is a sign you located yourself at a different location in the document tree when writing the code.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$xml->forecast->tabular->children()` to traverse the children of the xml:

```
<?php

$data = '<weatherdata>
 <forecast>
 <tabular>
   <time from="2015-09-25T20:00:00" to="2015-09-25T23:00:00" period="3">
      <symbol number="4" numberEx="4" name="Cloudy" var="04" />
   </time>
   <time from="2015-09-25T23:00:00" to="2015-09-26T05:00:00" period="0">
      <symbol number="9" numberEx="46" name="Light rain" var="46" />
   </time>
  </tabular>
  </forecast>
  </weatherdata>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

$froms = array();
$names = array();

foreach($xml->forecast->tabular->children() as $forecastItem){
    $attr = $forecastItem->attributes();
    $froms[] = $attr['from'];
    $attr2 = $forecastItem->symbol->attributes();
    $names[] = $attr2['name'];
}

print_r($froms);
print_r($names);
```

[Output](https://eval.in/private/0483364ee2160e):

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 2015-09-25T20:00:00
        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 2015-09-25T23:00:00
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => Cloudy
        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => Light rain
        )

)
```

Comment: @Alan thanks, I just noticed that too, seems like we edited it at the same time.

Comment: No problem, what matters is that it's now corrected. :)